# HP 5500 JD374A Port naming convention

Tags: switch, hp, hardware, switchport

Hi to all :) To most of you it'll prolly sound like a very silly question to ask, however to me as a fresh network trainee the answer is unfortunately not so obvious.

**So, the question is whether the first row (counting from the top) contains odd or even-numbered ports?**

The reason why I ask it at all is b/c my intuition would tell me that the little triangular icons above the ports indicate the position of a given port, so "▽1" would mean that the port highlighted in **blue** is going to be **Gi1/0/1** and so the port highlighted in **orange** is going to be **Gi1/0/2**.

[image: HP 5500's Ports]

However, when I look at the drawings by my more experienced colleagues at work, they seem to see it the other way round. I'm not entirely convinced though that they paid any attention to the vendor's pictograms and didn't do things out of habit based on their experience with Cisco hardware.

Which is why I hope that someone here, who's got a hands-on experience with HP switches will be able to clarify this issue for me.

PS. I have no physical access to the device so I cannot check it with my own hands by playing with cables...

Comment: At least all Procurve switches (I've seen) have port 1 on the top left and the odd-numbered ports in the top row. This looks weird to me...

Comment: Indeed, with ProCurve ones there's no confusion as the ports are very clearly denoted (Vide: [HP ProCurve 2610](https://noteboox.de/media/image/product/25171/lg/hp-procurve-switch-2610-24-pwr.jpg)). Unfortunately such is not the case with the 5500s (Vide: [HP 5500](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qqV74q09RdQ/maxresdefault.jpg))

Comment: Well, if you've got a switch at hand you can check by plugging a cable and see which port comes up and compare a port's MAC to a known device that's plugged in.

Comment: Err - on https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qqV74q09RdQ/maxresdefault.jpg the labeling is swapped to that on your pic above - just like on the Procurves.

Comment: My bad, I was looking for a photo of the switch where ports would be shown pretty up close but it turns out that A5500s are different from 5500s... The pic I used in my original post comes from the official HP guide and corresponds with our Visio diagrams (Vide: https://imgur.com/a/2KPtP) so that's the one on which our discussion should be based.

Comment: As for your earlier suggestion, yeah I know I could do that, unfortunately our company monitors these devices only remotely, so we never get to see any hardware with our own eyes. The lack of physical access to it is the very reason I am asking this question on the forum.

Comment: I guess I was too quick to lump all A5500s together as it seems to depend on the individual model - e.g. this one [here](https://ssli.ebayimg.com/images/g/UsEAAOSwbWZaUmjF/s-l640.jpg) (jd375a) has the symbols swapped compared to that earlier one (jg311a) or the system used on ProCurves...

Comment: This is just my "guess" of what has happened. Some HP switches have their labeling below the ports. Someone during design copied the bottom labeling from one model/line and moved the labeling to the top for this one and mistakenly flipped the triangles. No one looked closely and most everyone deploying them followed the "industry norm" of port 2 below port 1....until someone noticed the direction of the triangles and asked (here). If they had reversed the port order on this line, I am sure there would have been enough "noise" among network professionals for someone to be aware of it.